# How to create a dynamic table for json received from server

Tags: javascript, html, json, spring-mvc

i receive this json data from the ajax call to my server link

```
[{"reportType":"Thyroid","age":21,"gender":"Female","onThyroxine":false,"onAntiThyroideMed":false,"sick":false,"pregnant":false,"recentThryoidSurgery":false,"lithium":false,"goitre":false,"tumor":false,"hypopituitary":false,"tsh":120.0,"t3":120.0,"i131Treatment":false,"tbg":123.0,"t4U":12.0,"tt4":23.0,"fti":11.0}]
```

How do i parse this data? and convert it into a html table?

my code:

```
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";  
obj = { "table":str, "limit":20 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj); 
if (str == "") {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  return;
}
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); //Giving error
    {body to create table}
  }
```

Comment: If you `console.log(this.responseText);` in the function that handles the response, what do you see?

Comment: It responds with "undefined" @Archer

Comment: You need to figure out why the AJAX call is getting an undefined response then.  Until you do that you're unable to go any further.  What happens when you just open the Url in your browser?

Comment: [{"reportType":"Thyroid","age":21,"gender":"Female","onThyroxine":false,"onAntiThyroideMed":false,"sick":false,"pregnant":false,"recentThryoidSurgery":false,"lithium":false,"goitre":false,"tumor":false,"hypopituitary":false,"i131Treatment":false,"tbg":123.0,"fti":11.0,"tsh":120.0,"t3":120.0,"tt4":23.0,"t4U":12.0}]                           This is the response i get when going on the url directly. @Archer

Comment: Okay - so your AJAX call is incorrect.  You need to at least post the code that opens the request.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/thyroidReport",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/JSON")
   public ArrayList<thyroidMedicalReport> getDetails() throws IOException{
      return thyroidReportHandler.getDetails();
   }     Does that mean i have to change the GET to POST?

Comment: could you try with:  xmlhttp.open("get", "your file.json", true);

Comment: My json file is on the server. So i need to access it via that url. .json wont work then, right?

Comment: right. you need to use the correct url

Comment: I am unable to access the received json data. For instance, if i try to access reportType by myObj.reportType, i get the output at undefined. How do i access the data being stored?

Comment: can you try for `myObj[0].reportType`, also to generate `<table>` from `json` this one will help you [Datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Comment: yes that worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Here is an example of how you can do it (Just adjust the column names and you are good to go).

This is probably not the best solution but rather an idea of how you can do your task.

JS file:

```
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";  
obj = { "table":str, "limit":20 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj); 
if (str == "") {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  return;
}
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
// ----------------------------------------------    
let response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{"reportType":"Thyroid","age":21,"gender":"Female","onThyroxine":false,"onAntiThyroideMed":false,"sick":false,"pregnant":false,"recentThryoidSurgery":false,"lithium":false,"goitre":false,"tumor":false,"hypopituitary":false,"tsh":120.0,"t3":120.0,"i131Treatment":false,"tbg":123.0,"t4U":12.0,"tt4":23.0,"fti":11.0},{"reportType":"Thyroid","age":21,"gender":"Female","onThyroxine":false,"onAntiThyroideMed":false,"sick":false,"pregnant":false,"recentThryoidSurgery":false,"lithium":false,"goitre":false,"tumor":false,"hypopituitary":false,"tsh":120.0,"t3":120.0,"i131Treatment":false,"tbg":123.0,"t4U":12.0,"tt4":23.0,"fti":11.0}]));

    let htmlOutput = "<table border=2><tr><td>age</td><td>fti</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td><td>column name</td></tr>"

    for(let obj of response){
      console.log(obj);

      htmlOutput += "<tr>"; 

      for(let val in obj){
         //console.log(obj[val]);
         htmlOutput += "<td>"+obj[val]+"</td>"; 
      }

      htmlOutput += "</tr>"; 
    }
    htmlOutput += "</table>"; 

    console.log(htmlOutput);

    let tableContainer = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
    tableContainer.innerHTML = htmlOutput;
  // ----------------------------------------------   
  }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tableContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Working example:
https://jsbin.com/rosonotita/edit?html,js,output